# Invalid FilterExpression Syntax Error in AWS AppSync Resolver

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I have following resolver for getting items by list of Id with combination of `IN` Operator.

```
{
"version" : "2017-02-28",
"operation" : "Query",
"query" : {
    ## Provide a query expression. **
    "expression": "studentId = :id",
    "expressionValues" : {
        ":id" : { "S": "$ctx.args.studentId" }
    }
},
"filter": {
    "expression": "topicId IN :ids",
    "expressionValues" : {
        ":ids" : { "NS" : $ctx.args.topicIds }
    }
},
"index": "studentId-index",
}
```

Getting the following error:

```
{
"data": {
   "listStudentBookmarkedTopics": null
 },
 "errors": [
{
  "path": [
    "listStudentBookmarkedTopics"
  ],
  "data": null,
  "errorType": "DynamoDB:AmazonDynamoDBException",
  "errorInfo": null,
  "locations": [
    {
      "line": 2,
      "column": 3
    }
  ],
  "message": "Invalid FilterExpression: Syntax error; token: \":ids\", near: 
  \"IN :ids\" (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 
  ValidationException; Request ID: 
   R49QUD5LDF7KS83ABNTPLP10RBVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)"
  }
]
}
```

Comment: remove S in $ctx.args.topicIds and keep it as $ctx.args.topicId

Comment: But that is the argument that I am going to send. topicIds an array of topicId numbers represented by Number Set data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try changing your filter expression to the following?

```
"filter": {
    "expression": "contains(:ids, topicId)",
    "expressionValues" : {
        ":ids" : { "NS" : $util.toJson($ctx.args.topicIds) }
    }
}
```

This adds a call to **$util.toJson** and uses the **contains** DynamoDB filter expression.

Comment: Yeah. It worked. Also this can be used vice versa to compare attribute string set with query value to check if it is present there.